# What is the latest DirectX version officially compatible with Windows 98 SE?

Tags: directx, windows-98

I want to install Windows 98 SE for gaming old games. For this I need to know what is the latest DirectX version officially compatible with Windows 98 SE?

Comment: [DirectX 9.0c](https://www.microsoft.com/en-my/download/details.aspx?id=34429)

Comment: What did your research tell you? Searching for your question title answers your question (the 2nd link). The first link is now your question. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask): Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!"

Comment: I didn't trust second link, because didn't know are there official builds of DirectX or no. Though I agree that I should provide this information.

Comment: @Link - I provided you an official link to the last version that supported Windows 98SE.

Comment: Yeah, your points kinda prove that.

Answer (score 4):

9.0c *but* only specific versions it seems - you need a version that's not newer than 08 Dec 2006. Anything later needs at least windows 2000.

Answer (score 3):

[This website](http://www.falconfly.de/directx.htm) seems to be a good resource for this.

The latest version to support Windows 98 SE is version 9.0c, up to ***08 Dec 2006***. Beyond this point, support was dropped, although 9.0c was maintained up until **16 Mar 2009**, you won't be able to install this version. A direct link to the version that should work is [here](http://www.falconfly.de/downloads/DirectX-90c-x86-x86_64-Dec2006.zip).

Comment: Thank you. Can you also provide information - was there any Service Packs to Windows 98 SE? IS it true that Microsoft start providing Service Packs starting with Windows 2000?

Comment: @Link No official service packs were ever released for Windows 98 SE (I guess you could call the SE version a service pack of a kind). There are a number of unofficial service packs out there which are just a bundle of security updates and other fixes and features, but I don't think these would be essential to run any games.

Comment: @Link Please try to do some basic research before asking questions. Search for "windows 98 se service pack" > [The Complete List of Hotfixes, Updates, and Addons for Windows 98 Second Edition](http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/84886-the-complete-list-of-hotfixes-updates-for-windows-98se/) and [Unofficial Windows 98 SE Service Pack released](http://www.geek.com/news/unofficial-windows-98-se-service-pack-released-556492/)

Answer (score 0):

I believe Windows 98 goes all the way up to 9.0C. See http://www.oldversion.com/windows/directx/ It may be just Windows 2000 that does, but either way no Windows 9X goes past Direct 9.

Comment: Commentary about the site belongs on [meta] :)

Comment: it seems you've created 2 accounts on this site. [Kindly follow the process to merge them](https://meta.superuser.com/q/1418/241386). Don't use unregistered accounts or you'll lose access to the posts later and you also won't gain any reputation on the site